# Multiple values for a INT parameter in Paginated Report using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, filtering, powerbi-paginated-reports

I'm new creating paginated reports. I have to migrate a Visual in Power BI to a Paginated Report. For that I have copied the DAX query in the performance analyser, this is the code after cleaning a little bit:

```
// DAX Query
DEFINE
    VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
        TREATAS({@FiscalYear}, 'Calendar'[Year])

    VAR __DS0Core = 
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
            'Calendar'[Year],
            'Stores'[store_country],
            'Stores'[store_city],
            'Stores'[store_name],
            __DS0FilterTable,
            "Total_Transactions", 'Transaction_Data'[Total Transactions],
            "Weekend_Transactions", 'Transaction_Data'[Weekend Transactions],
            "Total_Cost", 'Transaction_Data'[Total Cost]
        )
        

EVALUATE
    __DS0Core
```

The value present in the code (1997) was replaced by @FiscalYear, and this was mapped to the report parameter @Year (INT - Not Multiple values). For one year, the process is working fine from Power BI:

[image]

However, when I change the parameter's attritube to allow multiple values, to select the two years, I'm getting this error :

> Cannot convert value '{ 1997,1998 }' of type Text to type Integer
> while processing column - [StaticColumn] -> Calendar[Year].

What do I need to change (in the parameter, Dax, Power BI) in order to get the expected result ?

I tried to modify the value of @FiscalYear to fx = Join(Parameters!Year.Value(0)), and other option but anyone worked.